# How to prevent automatic formatting of a section of flutter code by vs code or android studio?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, visual-studio-code, formatting

There are ways to disable the automatic formatting of Dart/Flutter codes completely in VS Code/Android Studio. But I need to do so only for a section of the code, not entirely. I have a large list of integers which I intend to write in certain number of rows x column ("arrangement"), but with automatic formatting the elements are formatted to occupy one element per line. This takes a lot of vertical space, and moving between the codes above and below is cumbersome.

I'm trying to find if there is some special code or method to skip automatic formatting for that particular section. Is it possible?

Comment: maybe `//ignore: lines_longer_than_80_chars` . But verify if that portion of code could be improved reading a json file or similar

Comment: @Mate, did not work!

Comment: "This takes a lot of vertical space, and moving between the codes above and below is cumbersome" cannot you use `part ...` and `part of ...` directives? more: https://theflutterist.medium.com/optimizing-imports-and-organizing-file-structure-in-flutter-73c08a5baf5e#:~:text=part%20of%20Directive%3A%20The%20part,maintaining%20a%20single%20library%27s%20scope.

Comment: @pskink, thank you for responding. I will try and see if it suits my case.

Comment: There is no general way to disable the Dart formatter for a specific section of code.  However, you *can* manually format collection literals, as explained by its FAQ: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#why-does-the-formatter-mess-up-my-collection-literals

Comment: @Mate `// ignore: ...` suppresses warnings from the *analyzer*.  It has nothing to do with the *formatter*.